# USB controllable display

Tags: c++, usb

I'm looking to be able to display status information using a small LED or a small LCD screen connected through USB.

All I need to display is very simple status (standby, error, running).

Is there anything already made, decent looking and programmable through C++?

Comment: You're looking for the USB class "HID" (Human Interface Device). This class is fairly easily programmable on modern OS'es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.mini-box.com/picoLCD-20x2-OEM) ? Since it's USB HID class, it should be fairly trivial to control from C++ on both Windows and Linux. (And I assume Mac OSX wouldn't be that hard either)

Answer (score 0):

The [Logitech G15](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/3498) has one.

Comment: Looks cool - but I would need just the screen.  I forgot to mention that for my project the device has to be pretty small.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mac: I believe I have included the essential parts of the answer here. The question is "where can I get one of those small displays", and my answer is "a Logitech G15 has one". The link was just to make it easier to find Logitech  G15s.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I respectfully disagree. If the link breaks, you'll still be able to Google for "Logitech G15", sure. But my personal opinion is that an answer on SE should give some *directly relevant, pertinent* information in its own right, otherwise it's no better than a canned Google search anyway. If that's what the OP actually needs, he shouldn't be asking the question - he should be Googling. Mind you, given that the answer's got no votes, the whole debate's probably a bit moot anyway... :)

Comment: @Mac: What other content would you expect me to put here? What "essential information" behind the link could have been added here? Answers that are just links are discouraged; sure. But a short answer that answers the question is just fine. Not every answer needs to be a novel.